# Allow users to add attachments in SFMC cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, file-storage

I have some use cases where I need to build a web form that includes a way for a site visitor to upload a file (jpeg, png, pdf types)

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434791/can-exacttarget-and-ampscript-use-a-form-to-upload-an-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have the [input from the form accept files](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) and then use [javascript to create a Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript) of this file.  From there you POST this string to your processing page (I usually do self post) and then use the [SFMC Content Builder API to create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_CreateAsset) this asset inside your Content Builder instance.

You would also need to have a [list of the Asset Ids and Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/base-asset-types.htm) inside SFMC stored in your page to match with the file attached for you to include inside your API call.

An example payload of this REST call is below:

Endpoint: `POST | /asset/v1/content/assets`

```
{
  "CustomerKey" : "Test_2Img",
  "AssetType" : {
    "name": "jpg",
    "id" : 23
    },
  "Name" : "Test_Img",
  "File" : "{{BASE64FileString}}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, we'll give this a try and see how it goes.