# Cloud page collects an attachment which needs to be sent to salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud

Client is using a cloud page as a sign up form and the attendee must attach documentation in order to sign up.  We would like to send that attachment via the connector from Marketing Cloud over to Salesforce and attach it to a SF object.  Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow users to add attachments in SFMC cloud page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/277914/allow-users-to-add-attachments-in-sfmc-cloud-page)